# How can i delete from the database multiple rows using a checkbox?

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

i'm trying to delete from the database multiple rows using checkboxes.

I have an html table inside a foreach loop to seek the table values.

And i want to put a delete button inside this table to delete all the values from a certain row.

But i dont know how to do that, i'm using this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && (!empty($_POST['checkbox']))){
$del_id = $_POST['checkbox']; 

foreach($del_id as $value){
   $sql = "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id='".$value."'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
}
```

And i have this code inside the foreach loop

```
<td><input style='width: 50px;' class='delete' value='delete' name='checkbox' type='checkbox'/></td>

<input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$key['job_id']." />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change your this code from

```
<td><input style='width: 50px;' class='delete' value='delete' name='checkbox' type='checkbox'/></td>
```

to something like

```
<td><input style='width: 50px;' class='delete' value='delete' name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox'/></td>
```

see the difference between `name='checkbox'` and `name='checkbox[]'`    and then in your php code .. write something like this

```
print_r($_POST);
```

you will get all the values .. try this .

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the checkbox as an array:

```
<input style='width: 50px;' class='delete' value='delete' name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox'/>
```

Also, instead of creating a new MySQL statement for each `checkbox` value received, you can use the `IN()` command:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && (!empty($_POST['checkbox']))){
$del_ids = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']); 

$sql = "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id IN('".$del_ids."')";
}
```

However, I strongly suggest using prepared statements. You also don't seem to sanitize the values in the `$_POST` variable — very dangerous.